# Orderer getting Exited while bootstrapping the HLF network using certificates generated by Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to use Fabric CA for generating certificates instead of cryptogen.
I am able to generate the certificates but when I try to start the network, the orderer is getting exited(peers are running fine). Below are the logs from orderer: [image]

I have tried searching for this problem and followed [this article](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/34343490)
But wasn't able to fix this issue.
I have made sure that the certificates generated are in proper directories like those generated by cryptogen.

Here is the certificate details of admincerts

```
subject= /C=US/ST=North Carolina/O=Hyperledger/OU=admin/CN=ordererAdmin
issuer= /C=US/ST=North Carolina/O=Hyperledger/OU=Fabric/CN=fabric-ca-server
```

I am currently using fabric **v1.4.2**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hey, seems like some attributes are missing in the cert

Comment: @NarendranathReddy which attributes ?

Comment: Can you please post the command or snippet of the function with which you're registering and enrolling your orderer node to the CA?